# Why rails app work sometimes and sometimes don't?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli

The thing is that I'm working on rails and my app is running on Heroku, yesterday I added the gem `carrierwave` to upload images to the app, but since that my app works only on some devices. It works in my pc and iphone 5 also in my ipad, but in the iphone X it doesn't. I read that some people had problems with the `image_tag` so to be sure I deleted it, I thought that it was the gem `devise` form to sign up so I deleted the fields that don't come with the `devise` form. still having the problem, in some devices my app works in others it doesn´t and this message shows up when I sign up with an Iphone X https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nqb1f.png
This is what I get in the logs:

```
2018-10-29T01:07:27.330739+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users" host=quiet-ravine-45803.herokuapp.com request_id=53986df2-c97d-4f5a-af54-9270808a67dd fwd="190.160.77.84" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=233ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https

2018-10-29T01:07:27.154283+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-10-29T01:07:27.154171 #4]  INFO -- : [53986df2-c97d-4f5a-af54-9270808a67dd] Started POST "/users" for 190.160.77.84 at 2018-10-29 01:07:27 +0000

2018-10-29T01:07:27.156381+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-10-29T01:07:27.156283 #4]  INFO -- : [53986df2-c97d-4f5a-af54-9270808a67dd] Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as HTML

2018-10-29T01:07:27.156566+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-10-29T01:07:27.156475 #4]  INFO -- : [53986df2-c97d-4f5a-af54-9270808a67dd]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"qsIs0JKQUb6Yri0d59zBYEIWFysjr9USNofGrEvNdUhTt87gM6AuOWGIK1x1y+LAMphGZ1n6hfuzVPFHOw+a8A==", "user"=>{"name"=>"caewer", "email"=>"pefs@gmail.com", "rut"=>"13", "address"=>"qweqwd", "phone"=>"56996349898", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}

2018-10-29T01:07:27.320359+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-10-29T01:07:27.320219 #4] DEBUG -- : [53986df2-c97d-4f5a-af54-9270808a67dd]   [1m[35m (0.7ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m

2018-10-29T01:07:27.322894+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-10-29T01:07:27.322714 #4] DEBUG -- : [53986df2-c97d-4f5a-af54-9270808a67dd]   [1m[36mUser Exists (0.9ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["email", "pefs@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]

2018-10-29T01:07:27.325619+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-10-29T01:07:27.325541 #4] DEBUG -- : [53986df2-c97d-4f5a-af54-9270808a67dd]   [1m[35m (0.9ms)[0m  [1m[31mROLLBACK[0m

2018-10-29T01:07:27.326271+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-10-29T01:07:27.326160 #4]  INFO -- : [53986df2-c97d-4f5a-af54-9270808a67dd] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 169ms (ActiveRecord: 2.5ms)

2018-10-29T01:07:27.329176+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-10-29T01:07:27.329086 #4] FATAL -- : [53986df2-c97d-4f5a-af54-9270808a67dd]   

2018-10-29T01:07:27.329299+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-10-29T01:07:27.329218 #4] FATAL -- : [53986df2-c97d-4f5a-af54-9270808a67dd] ActiveModel::RangeError (56996349898 is out of range for ActiveModel::Type::Integer with limit 4 bytes):

2018-10-29T01:07:27.329422+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-10-29T01:07:27.329322 #4] FATAL -- : [53986df2-c97d-4f5a-af54-9270808a67dd]   

2018-10-29T01:07:27.329641+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-10-29T01:07:27.329496 #4] FATAL -- : [53986df2-c97d-4f5a-af54-9270808a67dd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activemodel-5.2.1/lib/active_model/type/integer.rb:53:in `ensure_in_range'

2018-10-29T01:07:27.329644+00:00 app[web.1]: [53986df2-c97d-4f5a-af54-9270808a67dd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activemodel-5.2.1/lib/active_model/type/integer.rb:29:in `serialize'

2018-10-29T01:07:27.329646+00:00 app[web.1]: [53986df2-c97d-4f5a-af54-9270808a67dd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activemodel-5.2.1/lib/active_model/attribute.rb:55:in `value_for_database'

2018-10-29T01:07:27.329650+00:00 app[web.1]: [53986df2-c97d-4f5a-af54-9270808a67dd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/relation/query_attribute.rb:13:in `value_for_database'

2018-10-29T01:07:27.329652+00:00 app[web.1]: [53986df2-c97d-4f5a-af54-9270808a67dd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/quoting.rb:145:in `block in type_casted_binds'

2018-10-29T01:07:27.329654+00:00 app[web.1]: [53986df2-c97d-4f5a-af54-9270808a67dd] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/quoting.rb:145:in `map'
```

Comment: You need to take a look on the logs and share it in your question.

Comment: Following on @coderade's comment, you can use the command `heroku logs` to view your logs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-retrieval

Comment: Please don't include errors as images, or links to images. Adding the text to your question makes it indexable and adds important context to the question which in turn makes it easier to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error log:

```
2018-10-29T01:07:27.329299+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-10-29T01:07:27.329218 #4] FATAL -- : [53986df2-c97d-4f5a-af54-9270808a67dd] ActiveModel::RangeError (56996349898 is out of range for ActiveModel::Type::Integer with limit 4 bytes):

2018-10-29T01:07:27.156566+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-10-29T01:07:27.156475 #4]  INFO -- : [53986df2-c97d-4f5a-af54-9270808a67dd]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"qsIs0JKQUb6Yri0d59zBYEIWFysjr9USNofGrEvNdUhTt87gM6AuOWGIK1x1y+LAMphGZ1n6hfuzVPFHOw+a8A==", "user"=>{"name"=>"caewer", "email"=>"pefs@gmail.com", "rut"=>"13", "address"=>"qweqwd", "phone"=>"56996349898", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
```

These two lines tell you that the number 56996349898 is larger than the range of an integer's capable size. Write a migrate to change the column data type of `:phone` to string or bigint (from integer). To go into further detail about this, since the memory size of an integer is 4 bytes (32 bits), the largest that an integer can be is 2,147,483,647. Technically your phone number field is holding a number that is roughly 54 million values larger than what your integer type can hold, so you need to increase that. In some cases, it might even be better to represent your phone numbers as text/string, in case you wanted to do some string manipulation or formatting, such as adding hyphens or parentheses.